# Log4Net variable for host name?

Tags: log4net

Is there a parameter for the `ConversionPattern` that will include the host computer's name?
e.g.

```
<conversionPattern value="%hostname %date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
```

I can't find anything in the log4net documentation that lists what % fields are available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PatternLayout Class documentation page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html), use  the `log4net:HostName` property to get the name of the machine on which a specific event was logged.

You would use this in your config:

```
<conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName} %date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
```